# Using SnippetChooser in wagtail when the foreign key uses to_field

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I have a couple of models, Company and Sale. For a number of reasons that are not relevant to this discussion, I link the models together on a CharField. I would like to use a SnippetChooser on to select the company for the Sale model:

```
class Company(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Sale(models.Model):
    sale_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, to_field='account_id')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('sale_id'),
        SnippetChooserPanel('company'),
    ]
```

However, when I try to save a Sale model after choosing a company, i get an error that says the form submission is not valid.

Is there a way to let the SnippetChooserPanel know how to link this together?

Comment: Did you register `Company` using `@register_snippet`?

Comment: Yes. I can edit the snippet as usual. The only difference is that the snippet chooser can't display the data loaded from the database (e.g. shows it like there is no object linked, even though it is on db level), and when I link an object via the snippet chooser I can't save the object due to a validation error. The regular dropdown widget works fine, it's just not good for displaying massive amounts of possible related objects.

Comment: Probably a bug in Wagtail, then. Open an issue about this.

I’m also a bit surprised of the way you do this: what you probably want is to set `sale_id` & `account_id` as primary keys, that way Django will not define `id = AutoField(primary_key=True)` and you won’t have to use `to_field`.

Comment: Yes, I actually forgot to add the primary_key=True leaving me in this pickle now. I will probably go back and add that attribute for this project, but this is probably a bug in Wagtail as you say.